# looping through array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array dataset that I copied from chrome console that was produced by this code

```
    var cartarry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    console.log(cartarry)

products
:
Array(5)

{id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"}

1
:
{id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"}

2
:
{id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "3"}

3
:
{id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"}

4
:
{id: "1510-00-033-6312-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514540733034", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$43", quantity: "1"}

length
:
5
```

I want to loop through the array and get each of the id, name, price and quantity. I tried using this this code

```
cartarry.forEach(function(element) {
console.log(element);
})
```

but I got this error

> cartarry.forEach is not a function

i tried retrieving each manual with this

```
  cartarry[1]
```

but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong and how can I loop the array of products to obtain the property of each product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `cartarry.products` might hold the array. Try `cartarry.products.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a data structure like this:

```
{
  'products': [
    {id: "1510-01-312-3501-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1514542566148", name: "AIRPLANE UTILITY", price: "$90", quantity: "1"},
    ...
  ]
}
```

So in order to get to the ids you need to:

```
cartarry.products.forEach();
```

Go step by step, check what `cartarry.products` type is, it should be an Array.